# Align text to the right in JOptionPane

Tags: java, alignment, arabic, joptionpane

Is it possible to align the text to the right in JOptionPane? (I don't want to use JDialog) because I want to write some sentences in Arabic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a JPanel, align your text in your JPanel and then add the JPanel as the Object parameter of the JOptionPane.  Or use a JDialog (why the desire not to use one of these?).

Comment: Note for future readers that using a JPanel doesn't actually work because the overall layout of the dialog should also be reversed - OK button position and the icon should both be on opposite sides.

Answer (score 6):

```
 String message = "<html><body><div width='200px' align='right'>This is some text!</div></body></html>";
 JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel(message);
 JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, messageLabel);
```

Comment: Would work, except if font/L&F buttons are changed in any way. Besides, I always find the apparition of HTML in Swing labels as the sign of laziness (which is not that evil, but, in a sense, lacks elegance).

Answer (score 3):

Try using a JLabel on the JOptionPane and then use HTML to align it.

You can find more about [using HTML with Swing components here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by ... [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454887/align-text-to-the-right-in-joptionpane/6454968#6454968), you perfectly can use a JComponent as message in a [`JOptionPane#showMessageDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29). As a consequence, create a `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout`, put a `JLabel` in it with your text, use the righ set of `GridBagConstraints` to ensure the text is right-align, and voila ! A JOptionPane with a right-aligned text.