# JOptionPane.showOptionDialog() setComponentOrientaion right to left

Tags: java, swing

How is it possible to make swing JOptionPane dialog right to left?

Comment: what u mean by right to left??

Comment: Did you Google this at all? The first hit is another SO page, which I think has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454887/align-text-to-the-right-in-joptionpane

Comment: thanks @DuncanJones the links were useful

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6475320/230513).