# Java set direction for output programs

Tags: java, swing

I'm new in Java and below is simple code I wrote to learn Java.

I want to set `RIGHT TO LEFT` direction for output programs.  My language is `persian` as we write like Arabic `right to left` with right `text-align`

```
package ir.salam;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by tux-world on 7/8/14.
 */
public class JavaTuts {
    private static Scanner     in=  new Scanner( System.in );
    private static PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter( System.out,true );
    public  static void main( String args[])
    {
        String yourName;
        out.println("HI, please Choose one of this items.");
        menu();
        yourName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, "Please enter your name: ");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Hello " + yourName );
    }
    public static void menu(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "لطفا یکی از گزینه های زیر را انتخاب کنید:\n" +
                        "۱- ایجاد یک رکورد جدید\n" +
                        "۲- نمایش رکورد ثبت شده\n" +
                        "۳- خروج از برنامه",
                "منوی اصلی برنامه"
                , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align text to the right in JOptionPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454887/align-text-to-the-right-in-joptionpane)

Comment: Or is this a question about using different [Locales](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) in one program? I see some left-to-right english text there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Jframe and setting the orientation right to left:

```
JFrame jframe= new JFrame();  
jframe.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jframe, "لطفا یکی از گزینه های زیر را انتخاب کنید:\n" +
                    "۱- ایجاد یک رکورد جدید\n" +
                    "۲- نمایش رکورد ثبت شده\n" +
                    "۳- خروج از برنامه",
            "منوی اصلی برنامه", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has some examples which may help:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/bidi.html